# how to configure an arcgis server service to enable multiple editing

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, .net, arcgis-9.3

I'm using ArcGIS Server 9.3.1, ArcSDE, VS.NET 2008 and I'm trying to enable a service to be edited multiple times, the service its going to be public and it will be used to report emergencies and other situations that will require attention. I need some pointers on how to accomplish this.

Is it a good idea to have an editable map or its better to save the points coordinates to a database and in a report like app generate all the points at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a need to show points "live," I'd just store the x, y value. It's quicker, doesn't require edit capabilities on the service, and you can always make a layer from the stored points if need be.

(That being said, I'd still like to see someone else's answer regarding multiple edits. That'd be a nice way to do it, too, if live data is needed.)

Comment: I like this idea, but I have been working on the idea that for any set of data all you need is 3 feature services (point, line, polygon), which can be edited in subtypes to identify the FC it will be written to. I am still looking at some metrics to see if this actually improves performance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Feature Service:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_a_feature_service/005300000010000000/

Comment: Not possible with 9.3.1

Comment: need a Geodata Service at 9.3.1

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need is to create a Direct Connection to your SDE Database. This will allow external control, then you need to ensure that the data is registered as versioned, I would suggest creating a Web Editing Parent Version. Next Create a Geodata Service only including the layer you want to edit, this needs to be a dynamic layer, and have the data set to the parent version. It is also necessary that if you wish to keep all edits and not have then over written to set up the service as non-pooled. This will have hardware considerations

Next if you create a base map cached mapservice to overlay the editiable layer you have the basics running. Next I would place the tiled mapservice and the geodata service in an application for editing, this will allow for editing, and arrange the editing capability for the service. The last step is to build a commit button so that once the edits are completed the business tables can be automatically updated from the Editing version. I would suggest that this be done daily in the back end but just my opinion.

Hope this helps,
CDB